# Ubuntu-Server ответ от сервера ??????? ?????????? ? ??????? myQueue ? ??????? direct-exchange!, нет русских букв

Tags: java, ubuntu, spring, сервер, locale

При отправки реста на удаленный сервер

```
@PostMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestBody Map<String, String> map){
        log.info("Emit started to myQueue in \"common-exchange\"!{}, {}" , map.get("key"), map.get("message"));
        this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("myQueue2",map.get("message"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Успешно отправлено в очередь myQueue с помощью direct-exchange!");
    }
```

получаю ответ : ???????????

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

locale Ubuntu-Server

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Как или что нужно настроить, чтобы работать с русскими буквами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибку я устранил сам. Причина была в том что во время отправки реста я не указал в headers кодировку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]